# Full Width Toggle Dropdown Menu for Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to create a dropdown menu as in this site http://www.creuna.com/

I need the on click toggle option and the submenu to be a full width bar. I am planning to implement this is wordpress - genesis framework. Anyone know any plugin / script that has the functionality???? Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is a poorly formatted question. In order for us to be able to help you, you need to have a clear problem that you are having. We aren't going to be able to tell you how to impliment a menu on a wordpress site you havn't created, using a framework that has many options and themes. It's way too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the [UberMenu plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/ubermenu-wordpress-mega-menu-plugin/154703?ref=janecross). This plugin has full-width submenu option. Here the [demo](http://codecanyon.net/item/ubermenu-wordpress-mega-menu-plugin/full_screen_preview/154703).

Or with [MashMenu plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/mashmenu-wordpress-easy-mega-menu-plugin/5233213?ref=janecross), Here the [demo](http://demo.cactusthemes.com/#mashmenu).